# how to make a number of <h3> appear only with the beginning of their animation (css3)

Tags: css, animation

I'd like the three of my h3s to appear on the page only when their animation typewriter effect starts. Right now in this code variant while the first h3 (typewriter-advice) is undergoing the typewriter effect, the other two h3s (typewriter-jubilee and typewriter-rogue) just stand there waiting for their turn (animation-delay) to be animated.
While I want the other two h3's to appear only when their typewriting animation starts.
Would be grateful if you could give me a hand.

```
@keyframes blink-caret {
from, to { border-color: transparent }
50% { border-color:#26293c; }
 }


#typewriter-advice {
overflow: hidden;
border-right: 0.2px solid #26293c; /* The typwriter cursor */
white-space: nowrap;
margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
padding: 5px;
letter-spacing: .1em; /* Adjust as needed */
animation: 
  typewriter-advice 5.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end 5s;
 }
@-webkit-keyframes typewriter-jubilee {
from {width:0%}
to {width:100%}
 }

@keyframes blink-caret {
from, to { border-color: transparent }
50% { border-color:#26293c; }
  }

#typewriter-jubilee {
overflow: hidden;
border-right: 0.2px solid #26293c; /* The typwriter cursor */
white-space: nowrap;
margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
padding: 11px;
letter-spacing: .1em; /* Adjust as needed */
animation: 
  typewriter-advice 5.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes typewriter-rogue {
from {width:0%}
to {width:100%}
 }

@keyframes blink-caret {
from, to { border-color: transparent }
50% { border-color:#26293c; }
  }

 #typewriter-rogue {
overflow: hidden;
border-right: 0.2px solid #26293c; /* The typwriter cursor */
white-space: nowrap;
margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
padding: 5px;
letter-spacing: .1em; /* Adjust as needed */
animation: 
  typewriter-advice 5.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end 5s;
  animation-delay: 11s;
 }
```

**And here's HTML**

```
 <section class="full-length" id="one">
       <div class="third-width" id="advice">
          <img src="img/advice.png" alt="picture of advice for tech 
newbies"/>
       </div>
       <div class="third-width" id="advice-text">
           <h3 id="typewriter-advice"><span>Advice</span> Making Teamwork 
Work</h3>
           <p>This project was part of teamwork with other web developers 
around the world.
               The idea was to make a website via common contributions while 
keeping track of updates
               and changes in the main code. </p>
           </p>
       </div>
    </section>
    <section class="full-length" id="two">
        <div class="third-width" id="jubilee-text">
            <h3 id="typewriter-jubilee"><span>Jubilee</span> "I Celebrate 
Myself &amp; Sing Myself"</h3>
            <p>Jubilee Project was the first full-fledged attempt at 
portfolio websites.
                It came as a celebration of a new milestone change in tech 
skills.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="third-width" id="jubilee">
            <img src="img/jubilee.png" alt="jubilee project picture"/>   
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="full-length" id="three">
        <div class="third-width" id="rogue">
            <img src="img/rogue.png" alt="picture of advice for tech 
newbies"/>
        </div>
        <div class="third-width" id="rogue-text">
            <h3 id="typewriter-rogue"><span>Fresh</span> from the Start</h3>
            <p>Rogue Pickings was "fresh" in a few senses of the word.
                It was both a fresh start of a web dev career, and a website 
for fresh food and deliveries.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: why didn't you dump html codes?

Comment: @DogukanCavus sorry, fixed that.